# Display all tables that have a foreign key equal to a value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I'm going to attempt to describe this in the best way that I can. I need to test that a deletion is properly processing through all the tables in a database. The only tables that need to be checked are the ones that have a foreign key to the `Users` table with Primary Key `UserID`. I only want to pull in tables that have a foreign key equal to a specific value.

The following query pulls in all the tables that have a foreign key to `UserID`

```
    USE information_schema;
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM
  KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'Users'
  AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'UserID'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'erik_rm12_working41_main';
```

I just need a way to check that the tables listed have a value in their foreign key equal to a specific value, say 26.

Comment: You can delete from multiple tables in a single query. If it executes without errors all records are gone. That might be a better approach.

Comment: I'm not trying to delete in this query, simply check that a proper deletion occurred. That is beside the point of the question however. I need to know how to reference the foreign key values listed in all those tables in a equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to understand your requirement clearly...  Based on my understanding i given this query... You can try it and let us know, if anything required.

```
    SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey, 
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName, 
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName, 
    OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName, 
    COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName 

    FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
    ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id

     WHERE OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id)= '**<Table_Name>**'
```